# How can I do to put a space when I do the replacing using sed?

Tags: sed

I am trying to find `'hello'` in my file to replace that by     `'good bye'`

When I am using that command :

`sed "/'hello',/a     'good bye'" myfile.txt`

I got `'good bye'` instead of     `'good bye'`

Do you know how can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

To replace all occurrences of `'hello'` with a tab followed by `'good bye'`, you can use:

```
sed -i "s/'hello'/\t'good bye'/" myfile.txt
```